SQL query to summarize Audit table into new Aggregate Table
I have a ticket_audit table that logs for each ticket_id logs the status of the ticket, and the duration of each status.
Each ticket_id could have up to three statuses, (waiting, respond, and validation).
I want to be able to write a query that summarizes the information like in the desired output table below.
desired output columns and values

datetime - first datetimestamp of each ticket_id

agent

ticket_id

waiting_duration - for each ticket_id, there could possible be 2 or more duration for status = 'waiting'. I would like the duration to be summed together.

respond_duration - Not all ticket_id 's will have a respond duration

validation_duration - Not all ticket_id 's will have a validation duration so
ticket_audit table





datetime
agent
ticket_id
status
duration




9/1/24 5:47:43 PM
john
1001
waiting
1


9/1/24 5:47:48 PM
john
1001
waiting
7


9/1/24 5:47:53 PM
john
1001
respond
11


9/1/24 5:47:56 PM
john
1001
validation
15


9/1/24 5:47:48 PM
mary
1002
waiting
3


9/1/24 5:48:53 PM
mary
1002
waiting
4


9/1/24 5:48:56 PM
mary
1002
respond
45


9/1/24 5:49:56 PM
mary
1002
validation
53


9/2/24 12:04:39 AM
dave
1003
waiting
10


9/2/24 12:04:48 AM
dave
1003
respond
39


9/2/24 12:06:48 AM
dave
1003
validation
54


9/2/24 12:04:39 AM
john
1004
waiting
10


9/2/24 12:05:39 AM
john
1004
waiting
8


9/2/24 12:04:39 AM
mary
1005
waiting
3


9/2/24 12:04:48 AM
mary
1005
waiting
8


9/2/24 12:06:48 AM
mary
1005
respond
15



desired output



datetime
agent
ticket_id
waiting_duration
respond_duration
validation_duration




9/1/24 5:47:43 PM
john
1001
8
11
15


9/1/24 5:47:48 PM
mary
1002
7
45
53


9/2/24 12:04:39 AM
dave
1003
10
39
54


9/2/24 12:04:39 AM
john
1004
18
0
0


9/2/24 12:04:39 AM
mary
1005
11
15
0



Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Assumptions:

You want the earliest datetime
There is only a single agent per ticket_id
You want one row per ticket_id
The _duration columns are sums of the duration column (not math calculating time between statuses)

You could simply use:
select
  min(datetime) as datetime,
  min(agent) as agent,
  ticket_id,
  sum(case when status = 'waiting' then duration end) as waiting_duration,
  sum(case when status = 'respond' then duration end) as respond_duration,
  sum(case when status = 'validation' then duration end) as validation_duration
from table
group by ticket_id
order by ticket_id


Appreciate your help John. This worked for me.
